# How to use mssql to gradle?

Tags: sql-server, gradle, spring-tool-suite

I am using sts and make project:

[image]

and refresh all.
error message:

> Could not resolve: com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:4.0

how to fix it?

Comment: Curious, did my solution ever work?

Answer (score 4):

Change to:

```
implementation 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc'
```

You probably found a reference from somebody's code where they are using a local repository. As of November 11, 2016, mssql-jdbc is in Maven central. Much nicer to work with. It would appear that the 4.x versions are no longer officially available. All reference links that I have are redirecting to [their new JDBC homepage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server).

Version 4 is not in Maven central, so you'd have to obtain it and use it locally. [Here are the SQL Server JDBC drivers in Maven Repo](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/).